# Keyword argument repeated in Flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I keep getting the 'keyword argument repeated' error, I am trying to create the page selection system. Thanks in advance for any help.

I tried the following code (I think the error is related to jinja templates in some way):

```
@users.route("/<username>")
def user_posts(username):
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()
    blog_posts = BlogPost.query.filter_by(author=user).order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)

    return render_template('user_blog_posts.html', user=user, blog_posts=blog_posts)
```

This is the python code calling the HTML page where the error is taking place. The HTML page (user_blog_posts.html):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Welcome {{user.username}}</h1>
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/'+user.profile_image)}}" alt="Error! Picture not found.">
    </div>
</div>

{% for post in blog_posts.items %}

<h2><a href="{{url_for('blog_posts.blog_posts', blog_posts_id=post.id)}}">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
<p>Written By: <a href="{{url_for('user.user_post', username=post.author.username)}}">{{post.author.username}}</a></p>
<p class="text-muted">Published on: {{post.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}}</p>
<br>
<p>{{post.text}}</p>
<br> {% endfor %}

<nav aria-label="Page Navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">

        {% for page_num in blog_posts.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_current=1, right_current=2) %} {% if blog_posts.page == page_num %}
        <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link" href="{{url_for('user.user_posts', username=user.username, page=page_num)}}">{{page_num}}</a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="{{url_for('user.user_posts', username=user.username, page=page_num)}}">{{page_num}}</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %} {% endfor %}

    </ul>
</nav>

{% endblock content %}
```

This is the error code. The HTML file has 35 lines but it says that the error is in line 40

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "D:\Desktop\Education\Python\Flask\14.Blog\blog\users\views.py", line 131, in user_posts
return render_template('user_blog_posts.html', user=user, blog_posts=blog_posts)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 138, in render_template
ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_template
return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 125, in load
code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 588, in compile
return self._compile(source, filename)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 551, in _compile
return compile(source, filename, 'exec')
File "D:\Desktop\Education\Python\Flask\14.Blog\blog\templates\user_blog_posts.html", line 40

    ^
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
{% for page_num in blog_posts.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_current=1, right_current=2) %} {% if blog_posts.page == page_num %}
```

`right_current` argument is repeated, as the error states.